# Laravel 4.2 - Left Join isseu when using Eloquent paginate function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I am facing problem when executing following query :

```
$businesses = Business::leftJoin('business_stats','businesses.id','=','business_stats.business_id')
    ->leftJoin('restaurant_coupons',
        function($join){
            $currentdate    =   date("Y-m-d");
            $join->on('restaurant_coupons.business_id','=','businesses.id')
                ->whereNull('restaurant_coupons.deleted_at')
                ->where('restaurant_coupons.starts','<=',$currentdate)
                ->where('restaurant_coupons.ends','>=',$currentdate);
        }
    )
   ->where('is',1)
    ->select('businesses.*'
                ,'business_stats.*'
                ,DB::raw( $nullQuery )
                ,'businesses.id as id','restaurant_coupons.code')  
    ->orderBy($orderBy,$orderByOrder)
    ->paginate(30);
```

Following is the query log for prepared statement by Laravel:

```
Array
(
[query] =>
            select
                `businesses`.*,
                `business_stats`.*,
                IFNULL(tit_rank,100000) as titrank,
                `businesses`.`id` as `id`,
                `restaurant_coupons`.`code`
            from
                `businesses`
            left join `business_stats` on
                    `businesses`.`id` = `business_stats`.`business_id`
            left join `restaurant_coupons` on
                `restaurant_coupons`.`business_id` = `businesses`.`id` and
                `restaurant_coupons`.`deleted_at` is null and
                `restaurant_coupons`.`starts` <= ? and
                `restaurant_coupons`.`ends` >= ?
            where
                `businesses`.`deleted_at` is null and
                `is_bolo` = ?
                order by
                    `titrank` desc
                limit 30 offset 0
[bindings] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-09-01
        [1] => 2015-09-01
        [2] => 2015-09-01
        [3] => 2015-09-01
        [4] => 1
    )

[time] => 0.55
)
```

After executing the query I get null as output. But it should return result.

After some debugging, I found that if I remove `->paginate(30)` and add `->get()` then get result as expected.

I came to know that the `paginate` function binding the data twice in the query. That is my query is expecting only 3 parameters but in the paginate function the query is called twice and for the second time its passing two more parameters that is 5 parameters.

If you see the parameter array has 5 elements where the first and second elements are repeated at third and fourth position again.

Comment: Do you have more than 30 rows in your Business model ? Also you can try to comment out the line **->orderBy($orderBy,$orderByOrder)**

Comment: @HalfWay then how I can perform order ?

Comment: first we need to fix the error THEN surely we can use orderBy. what about your result ??

Comment: @HalfWay sorry but I can try everything but it's not solve my problem. and please read my question proper I've mention that where I have found problem.